# Don't Extend Edges Under Top Bar, but with white/translucent navbar?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I had weird extra space between the navbar and the top cell of my table view, so I searched around and disabling "Extend Edges > Under Top Bars" got rid of the space, but now my nav bar is grey and boring. "Adjust Scroll View Insets" has no effect either way, btw.

Is there a way to have a normal-looking nav bar without the extra space??

Here's how it looks with the extra space

[image: Here's how it looks with the extra space]

Here's how it looks with "Extend Edges > Under Top Bars" turned off:

[image: Here's how it looks with "Extend Edges > Under Top Bars" turned off]

Comment: Can you pls add screenshot or code snippet you tried @jonathan

Comment: @Maddyヅヅ - done! (no code involved in tableview setup)